# Legacy OpenGL Textures

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Using LWJGL and PNGDecoder and I've found the documentation to be less than helpful when it comes to textures. I understand the basic concepts concerning them, but I don't know what functions to call (except the calls to create the texture ByteBuffer, upload the data, but not to actually make use of it), and I have no idea what to use in legacy OpenGL (in this case, GL 1.4), as otherwise shaders are required, and I wasn't aware of GL 1.9 and lower making use of shaders.

I am using this to teach game development to other students, which I stated in a previous post. I understand the concepts concerning them, I just don't understand what actual calls to make to get it all to render. I suppose that wasn't clear last time, I need to know the specifics, but I have conceptual knowledge. Sorry for leaving out that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no OpenGL-1.9, the last OpenGL-1.x version was OpenGL-1.5.

If you're interested in legacy OpenGL I suggest you read the NeHe tutorials then. Outdated, but in your case what you're looking for. [NeHe Lesson 6 – Texture Mapping](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_mapping/12038/) should cover your interests. There's even a [LWJGL port source code download](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lwjgl/lesson06.jar) for it.

Comment: Well now I feel stupid. I completely forgot about the jump. I'm in a bit of a rush for other reasons. Anyway, thank you for the resources, I'll be sure to look at them! Actually, that LWJGL port is just a .jar, is there some source somewhere that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Ah, opened it with 7-zip and found everything I needed. Odd, it was labelled as an executable .jar.